goo.gl links will be broken in a year
google will be sunsetting their link shortener service on august 25th 2025. There's less than 7 examples of this on the site, and it would be semi trivial to fix these. Subdomains like photos.goo.gl should work, but its probably a good idea to review these.
I think I can fix these with minimal disruption but its good to have things like this documented. I already have a plan in mind on what to do and will be trickling in these edits if there's no objection.

Do you plan to look at the comments, too? (BTW would the tag ([meta-tag:hyperlinks]) be suitable here?)

I didn't think they far but that would be an easier fix

comments all fixed

Please keep in mind the title is incorrect, as it will shut down next year: August 25, 2025

AH I guess I misread it. ._. Gives me more time to fix it :D
